# Issue in flattening Json file in python

Tags: python, json, pandas, parsing

I have a json file that contains the record of goals scored at the minutes of the game.
I tried to flatten it using the following code:

```
data_Loc ='Season Fixtures.json'
with open(data_Loc) as data_file:    
    d= json.load(data_file)  
df_Fixtures = pd.io.json.json_normalize(d,'matches')
```

The output is as follow:

[image: Pls see here]

Then I convert goals to series using:

```
df_goal = df_Fixtures.goals.apply(pd.Series)
```

and the output is as follow:

[image]

It includes another dictionary in the columns.

How can I convert goals column directly to periods?

The input data file can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1A7zJ9M1KtqlhZRAoWYD0FhQcr9vwtnst)

Can anyone advise me how to flatten to the last part of goal column?
That means goals columns will be converted in to multiple columns such as Period, minutes, playerId,TeamId, Type.

To include **matchId**, I create a new data frame as follow and combine with previous data frame advised by Jez as follow:

```
df_MatchID = pd.io.json.json_normalize(d,'matches')
df_MatchID = df_MatchID[['matchId']]
df_Fixtures_details = pd.concat([df_MatchID,df_Fixtures],axis =1)
```

The output is as follow ( Other columns shows NaN:)
[image]

Thanks
Zep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
df_Fixtures = pd.io.json.json_normalize(d, ['matches','goals'])

print (df_Fixtures.head())
   minute      period  playerId  teamId  type
0      14   FirstHalf    206314    3161  goal
1      72  SecondHalf     20661    3204  goal
2      78  SecondHalf    206314    3161  goal
3       3   FirstHalf    300830    3187  goal
4      72  SecondHalf     21385    3187  goal
```

EDIT:

```
data_Loc ='Season Fixtures.json'
with open(data_Loc) as data_file:    
    d= json.load(data_file)['matches'] 

df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(d, ['goals'],'matchId')

print (df.head())
   minute      period  playerId  teamId  type  matchId
0      14   FirstHalf    206314    3161  goal  2759508
1      72  SecondHalf     20661    3204  goal  2759508
2      78  SecondHalf    206314    3161  goal  2759508
3       3   FirstHalf    300830    3187  goal  2759507
4      72  SecondHalf     21385    3187  goal  2759507
```

Comment: Thanks, Jez. If I want to include matchId as well, create another data frame as follow:

**df_MatchID = df_MatchID[['matchId']]
df_Fixtures_details = pd.concat([df_MatchID,df_Fixtures],axis =1)**
But the output showes all Nan except matchId columns

Comment: Jez, I have updated in my question for combining matchId and df_Fixtures

Comment: @Zephyr - give me some time, please,

Comment: No Worries. Take your time. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @Zephyr - If there are no golas, emty list, is possible remove `matchId` ?

Comment: yeah. should not be problem to remove it if there is not data in goal.Thanks

Comment: Thanks Jez, Can you please explain on the code briefly so that I can understand more. It worked.Appreciate your advice.

Comment: @Zephyr - Really hard expalin it, because [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) is also poor :( Maybe help a bit [this](https://www.kaggle.com/jboysen/quick-tutorial-flatten-nested-json-in-pandas)

Comment: Thanks Jez. I will read it. I hv a few questions on reading APi that is authenticated. Can I ask you personally on that if you don’t mind?

Comment: @Zephyr - Sure, but I have no experience with `APi that is authenticated` :(